# Comparison of words from the database and output of the result

Tags: php, foreach

I need to check the words received from the database with the user's entered word and if there is a match, then output its value from the database, and if not, then output what the user entered.

The code below works fine if there is a match.

```
function d_typeplace_morf($d_typeplace)
{

    global $wpdb;
    $typeplace_results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT vozmozhnyi_variant_mesta, ego_slovoforma_v_predlozhnom_padezhe FROM dEzpra_jet_cct_tip_mest_obrabotki');

    if ($typeplace_results) {
        foreach ($typeplace_results as $typeplace_result) {
            $d_typeplace_raw = mb_strtolower($typeplace_result->vozmozhnyi_variant_mesta);
            $d_typeplace_morf = mb_strtolower($typeplace_result->ego_slovoforma_v_predlozhnom_padezhe);
            $d_typeplace = mb_strtolower($d_typeplace);


            if (stripos($d_typeplace, $d_typeplace_raw) !== false) {
                echo $d_typeplace_morf;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm an amateur in PHP, just learning. And I can't figure out how to output `$d_typeplace` if no match is found.

I tried to add

```
else {
    echo $d_typeplace;
}
```

, but I get an array of words from the user entered.

I will be grateful for any help. Also for any suggestions for improving this code.

---Addition---

I apologize for my English. This is a problem in the Russian language, I need to take into account the morphology. To do this, the database has a list of words and their analog, for example, `X = Y`. I get these words and compare what the user entered. If he entered `X`, then we output `Y`. If he led `Z`, which is not in the database, then we output `Z`.

Thus, we check `$d_typeplace` with `$d_typeplace_raw` and if there is a match, we output `$d_typeplace_morf`, which is equal to `$d_typeplace_raw`. And if not, then `$d_typeplace` (it contains the value that the user entered).

Oh, I'm sorry, I understand myself that I'm explaining stupidly)

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming you were trying to add the else like this?

```
function d_typeplace_morf($d_typeplace)
{

    global $wpdb;
    $typeplace_results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT vozmozhnyi_variant_mesta, ego_slovoforma_v_predlozhnom_padezhe FROM dEzpra_jet_cct_tip_mest_obrabotki');

    if ($typeplace_results) {
        foreach ($typeplace_results as $typeplace_result) {
            $d_typeplace_raw = mb_strtolower($typeplace_result->vozmozhnyi_variant_mesta);
            $d_typeplace_morf = mb_strtolower($typeplace_result->ego_slovoforma_v_predlozhnom_padezhe);
            $d_typeplace = mb_strtolower($d_typeplace);


            if (stripos($d_typeplace, $d_typeplace_raw) !== false) {
                echo $d_typeplace_morf;
            } else {
                echo $d_typeplace;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which was outputting an array because the for loop was continuing, if you add a break like so...

```
echo $d_typeplace;
break;
```

It should stop outputting an array. Depending on your use case you could however perform similar functionality directly in your sql query using [LIKE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) ...

```
function d_typeplace_morf($d_typeplace)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $typeplace_results = $wpdb->get_results('
        SELECT ego_slovoforma_v_predlozhnom_padezhe 
        FROM dEzpra_jet_cct_tip_mest_obrabotki 
        WHERE vozmozhnyi_variant_mesta LIKE %' . $d_typeplace . '%');

    if ($typeplace_results) {
        //Echo result
    } else {
        echo $d_typeplace;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This says a lot, but, unfortunately, it's not what you need. I have completed the answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot quite understand what you are asking: you need to output the string entered by the user, but you can only print an array?

If this is the case, I think you parsed the string before, in order to therefore you need to do join again the values contained in the array.

Try with:

```php
else {
    echo implode(" ", $d_typeplace);
}
```

--- EDITED ---

Try with:

```php
function d_typeplace_morf($d_typeplace)
{

    global $wpdb;
    $typeplace_results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT vozmozhnyi_variant_mesta, ego_slovoforma_v_predlozhnom_padezhe FROM dEzpra_jet_cct_tip_mest_obrabotki');

    if ($typeplace_results) {

        $found = false;

        foreach ($typeplace_results as $typeplace_result) {
            $d_typeplace_raw = mb_strtolower($typeplace_result->vozmozhnyi_variant_mesta);
            $d_typeplace_morf = mb_strtolower($typeplace_result->ego_slovoforma_v_predlozhnom_padezhe);
            $d_typeplace = mb_strtolower($d_typeplace);


            if (stripos($d_typeplace, $d_typeplace_raw) !== false) {
                echo $d_typeplace_morf;
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$found) {
            echo $d_typeplace;
        }
    }
}
```

But I think it would be more efficient, if you implemented the second code snippet written by @Luke.T

Comment: Sorry for my English. I have completed my question, please take a look, maybe it will be clearer this way.

Comment: ok, probably you just need to add a boolean wether the word has been found - I edit my answer in order to attach the code